# Can't login with Java Configuration and Spring Security 3.2

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm having trouble after switch my application to Spring security 3.2 and Java Configuration. Originally it was configured with xml but once I've made all the changes to use annotations every time I try to access to localhost:8080/mysite/login I have this error "No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/mysite/login] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher". This is my configuration:

```
public class SpringMvcInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[] { AppConfig.class };
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return null;
}

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[] { "/" };
}
}
```

AppConfig.java

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({ "com.mypackages.*" })
@Import({ DatabaseConfig.class, SecurityConfiguration.class, SocialConfig.class })
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:/mysite.properties"})
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    //in this class I define the viewResolver, messageSource, localeResolver, some properties, etc, but I don't think they would be necessary for my problem
}
```

"configure" method at SecurityConfiguration.java

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/welcome")
            .permitAll()
    .and()
        .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/logout")
            .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
    .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/welcome*").authenticated()
    .and()
        .rememberMe()
    .and().headers().xssProtection().frameOptions().httpStrictTransportSecurity()
    .and()
        .apply(new SpringSocialConfigurer());
}
```

web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>
            org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            com.myapp.config.AppConfig
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
    <param-value>
        org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
    </param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>com.myapp.config.AppConfig</param-value>
</context-param>
```

As far as I understand, with the login page setted in the "configure" method (SecurityConfiguration.java) should be enough to show the login page when I access to localhost:8080/mysite/login, I've been reading some examples I don't think the error is on the security configuration, am I missing something?.

Any help will be appreciated

**UPDATE**
I've been searching and it seems like my error was to include both web.xml and an extension of `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer` so I decided to remove the web.xml, and modify `SpringMvcInitializer`:

```
@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[] { AppConfig.class, SecurityConfiguration.class };
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[] { DatabaseConfig.class };
}
```

But still have the same error `No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/siteserver/login] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'`, pleeeaaaase does anybody has a clue about what's going on?

Comment: did you enable @EnableWebMvcSecurity ?

Comment: and what about that contextPath /mysite ? is it declared ?

Comment: Hi @user1289300, sorry for the late response and thanks for your help. Regarding your questions, yes to both: I did enable the EnableWebMvcSecurity and also declared the /mysite path

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a spring security, i think you should also configure application context.xml which should be in your WEB-INF folder.

Change the location of your context config. I believe it should be your applicationContext.xml and all the confifuration will go inside that.
`<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>`

You can also try adding the listener class in your web.xml
`<listener>
   <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
   </listener-class>
</listener>`

Comment: Hi @Mayank, thanks for your suggestion, but the idea is to replace the application-context.xml file with all the annotated dependencies. I think my mistake is due to have an web.xml and also to extend the AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer, I think I should remove the web.xml